# how to save ffprobe result in json

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

i am using the following:
ffprobe -i bunny.mp4 -v quiet -select_streams v -print_format json -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type|grep -B 1  pict_type=I

so i can save time of index frames in json file.
also the command works just fine without the:
 "print formqt json",
it doesnt seem to work after i add it.
i have tried "print format json " commands like:
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "lolwut.mp4" 
and it works just fine.
what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep is looking for the wrong string.

It should be

`ffprobe -i bunny.mp4 -v quiet -select_streams v -print_format json -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type | grep -B 1 "\"pict_type\": \"I\""`

Comment: it still doesnt generate json ,the output is in the following format: "pkt_pts_time": "0.000000",
            "pict_type": "I"
--

Comment: It won't be valid json after you grep it. You can come close by using `-B 2 -A 1` in grep